# R version 4.0.2, Windows 10, Error: In mean.default(combined[colname], na.rm = TRUE) : argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA

Tags: r, function, mean

- Data contains 332 separate csv files in a directory.
- Tried *sapply* on the data frame, returned the type as *numeric.*
- Tried reading other answers, couldn't use the info provided

**Function:-**

```
somemean<- function(directory, colname, id=1:332)
{
    files_list = list.files(directory,full.names=TRUE)[id]
    combined <- data.frame()
    for(i in id)
    {
        combined<-rbind(combined, read.csv(files_list[i]))
    }
    result<-mean(combined[colname], na.rm=TRUE)
    print(result)
}
```

**Calling like this:-**

```
somemean("specdata", "sulfate", 1:10)
```

Comment: This is from coursera's R programming course, right? There are lot of questions already available on SO which do the same thing. For example check these posts - https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Br%5D+pollutantmean

Comment: The error message does not match your code.